# PHP sockets not working when sending a 2nd command

Tags: php, apache, sockets

I am writing a client app that is connecting to a telnet server. Both client and server are on a raspberry pi. I need to send multiple commands to the server and the send is going through properly but the return is coming back empty after the first send command

```
$message1 = "get a";
$message2 = "get b";

socket_write ($socket , $message1, strlen($message1));

// get server response
$line = socket_read($socket,8192,PHP_NORMAL_READ);

//Parse json return
$json = json_decode($line, true); 
$a = $json["request_id"];
echo $a;
sleep(2);


socket_write ($socket , $message2, strlen($message2));
 // get server response
$line2 = socket_read($socket,8192,PHP_NORMAL_READ);

//Parse json return
$json = json_decode($line2, true); 
$b = $json["request_other_id"];
echo $b;
```

echo $a is returning data but echo $b is empty. Looking at the server logs, the command for $message2 is flagged as a success

echo $line2 is also returning blank

Comment: I noticed that if I point my script to other this same server application sitting on a Pi, CentOS, and windows, I get the same issue. Is it possible that this is an apache config issue on my end where my client is sitting? I am using the default apache2.conf

Comment: I switched to using Python for socket access and works like a charm